# svn: removing an external in the working copy?

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I moved one of my (single-file) externals to another directory, but its presence persists in my working copy. If I delete the file and then `svn update`, it gets restored.

How can I get rid of the external? It's no longer present in `svn:externals` in the directory in question.

Comment: You didn't by any chance forget to commit the directory after modifying the svn:externals property?

Comment: nope, did that first thing, but thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem, see:

http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3351 - can't remove file externals.

It was fixed in 1.7, but in 1.6 one has to checkout a fresh working copy to get rid of the file.

Comment: or create empty file and delete with next command: svn propset svn:externals -F svn.externals .

Answer (score 1):

Found a fix: I deleted the parent directory of the file in question, and then did an update. SVN did not recreate the phantom file.